# Android Studios .xml programming errors

Tags: java, android

While trying to program a basic interface for an app I ran into a problem where the `.xml` will not allow me to drag the pre-programmed widgets onto the phone design. I haven't touched the initial code and error messages keep appearing. It looks like there's an error in how I named my file but I'm not sure what corrections to make.

**The Error Messages:**

```
11:23:59 AM FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\McKenzie\.AndroidStudio1.5\system\vcs-users\Do You Hear What I Hear?.8b4edad9.len (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
11:24:01 AM Gradle sync started
11:24:04 AM NullPointerException: null
11:24:26 AM Gradle sync completed
11:24:26 AM IOException: Problem trying to create temp directory with prefix: 'Do You Hear What I Hear?' suffix: 'aar_cache' path: 'C:\Users\McKenzie\AppData\Local\Temp': Unable to create temporary file C:\Users\McKenzie\AppData\Local\Temp\Do You Hear What I Hear?0aar_cache
11:24:27 AM Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
11:24:29 AM Gradle build finished in 3s 527ms
```

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: provide your code.

Comment: I'm not sure how or why there are files being made within the `HOME\.AndroidStudio1.5\system\vcs-users` folder

Answer (score 2):

What I would suggest is avoid using (space) in the file name. Use a underscore (_) instead. And also remove the `?` in the end. This should solve the problem.
Eg
`Do You Hear What I Hear?` change this to `do_you_hear_what_i_hear`